# How to reduce all of my page's font-size by 20% (NOT EM)

Tags: css, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, font-size

I'm currently working on a page with internationalization and just for the japanese language all of the fonts should be reduced by 20% (because japanese kanjis are really big compared to alphabeth characters).

I already have the css rule that changes the fontsize only when it changes to Japanese, but I can't just shrink it with EM because i have headings, paragraphs and many other sizes of texts and using (0.8em) shrinks all of them differently and not in the expected behavior.

I tried using `font-size: 80%`. `font-size: calc(auto - 20%)` and none of them worked.

Do you have any other ideas? i'm using Sass ( scss) in case it might be handy. if it's not possible with Scss how can i accomplish it with JS (can be vanilla or vue)

Comment: `font-size: 80%` is what you should use. And [it works](https://prnt.sc/va6tyt). If it doesn't in your case, you have to provide a [mcve] which would allow inspection to see why it doesn't in your example.

Comment: Percentages are not working as expected and i don't know why- I even tested font-size: 100%, all of the fonts should remain and they don't. Is there any extra configuration or tips you can give me? @tao

Comment: I cannot understand why % does not work for you, you should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Update: @mmaismma The 80% rule was applied to " * " all of the items. some items were nested and it applied 80% more than once, that's what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

If `%` is not working for you for some reason, why don't you try using [**font-relative units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths)?

I would recommend you use `ch` or `ex`.

- `ch` compares the width of the letter `0` (zero) in the font.
- `ex` compares the x-height of the element's font. On fonts with the "x" letter, this is generally the height of the lowercase `x` letter in the font.
  [image: Image showing x-height]

Both of the units should work fine with a Japanese font.

Answer (score 0):

Although my other answer should work fine, one more thing you can do to fix your problem is to wrap all Japanese text in `span` with `class="jp"` and apply `font-size: 80%` to `.jp`.